# API stops working due to SSL implementation in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax, http, ssl, https

I have consumed a weather API using below code:

```
function getWeatherData() {
var temperature = 0;
var dfd = $.Deferred();

var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.1/find/name?q=London,%20UK&units=metric&mode=jsnop";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    url: url + "&callback=?",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
        temperature = data.list[0].main.temp;
        $('[id$=AirTemperature]').css('visibility', 'visible');
        $('[id$=AirTemperature]').css('display', '');
        var F = temperature * 9 / 5 + 32;
        $('[id$=AirTemperature]').text(Math.round(F) + '\u00B0 F / ' + Math.round(temperature) + '\u00B0 C');
    },
    error: function(errorData) {
        alert("Error while getting weather data :: " + errorData.status);
    }
});
```

}

now, i have implemented SSL certificate for my website, this method has stopped working. I have tried to make it working, by removing "http" from the URL, but it didn't work, Please help me how can i resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I am not going to leave an answer because my response is not "answer-worthy" but this *feels* a lot like a cross site scripting / JS Security problem.  You are basically posting data from a secure site (encrypted with SSL) to an unsecure site. You know how you get those warnings in your browser when there is mixed content on the page? Same basic concept I would suspect.

Comment: @Goblyn27 i am posting data from unsecure to Secure website.